# NoClassDefFoundError after importing package

Tags: java, exception

I have a program on codeboard.io at the following link https://codeboard.io/projects/5714 
the aim of the project is:-

- Implement the Employee class and its three child classes (ManagementEmployee, EngineeringEmployee and AdministrationEmployee), with all the necessary attributes and methods. Do not include any other attribute or method apart from the ones previously described.
- Write a Staff class, which first creates an array with all the employees in the company, and then prints the complete staff list on the screen. This class must also calculate and print the total salary for each of the three departments.

after an all nighter i was able to get rid of the compilation error and write what i thought was a correct program but for some reason i get a NoClassDefFoundError when i run this, anyone have any guesses as too why this is happening, because i have created packages and imported them in the executing class but still no result. Help is appreciated, P.S. i couldnt post the codes here becasue for some reason the formatting was off but uoi get a direct link to the program from here where you can see all the files i have made and run the program as well as edit it.

Comment: *anyone have any guesses*: that's not how you should deal with errors. Instead of guessing, you should carefully read and understand the exception stack trace, examine the code and the way it's being run, and then try to draw conclusions. Since you haven't posted anything, we can't do and deduction. Post the complete exception stack trace, the code, and tell us how you run your program, where the files are, etc..

Comment: I tried that for 4 hours, and I have posted Tue link to the online IDE where all these things can be seen, the code and the exceptions were too long to fit into the question with proper formatting, and BTW please stop being so condescending that is just my manner of speaking, what I mean by that is does anyone know why this is happening

Comment: "Since you haven't posted anything, we can't do and deduction"                         if you had even bothered to read the question you would have seen that the program as well as all the errors can be seen here https://codeboard.io/projects/5714

Comment: Listen. You're a StackOverflow newbie. Half of the questions posted by newbies here don't include the **relevant** code and the complete error message. Yours is no exception. Let me get the rules of StackOverflow straight. I didn't write them. Here they are: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it __in the question itself__*. You fail on all criteria. Now you can take it personally, or you can take it as constructive criticism.

Comment: I have written the desired behaviour in the 2 points and the program IS ON THE LINK!!! I don't know why you keep ignoring that, but if you would just look at the program you would know the exact error type, and like I said I didn't write it here cause it didn't fit

Comment: And I'm not taking any offense I'm just getting annoyed because you have to even read the question and I wouldn't post the problem here unless I was really stuck. I worked on this for 6 hours unable to find the problem that's why I'm asking someone to take a look at the program and in the staff.java and employee.java files that are on the link I provided

Comment: The code must be **in the question itself**. If it's too large to fit, then it means you're posting too much of it. It means you're trying to post everything instead of posting the **relevant** part of it. The complete exception stack trace must also be **in the question itself**. Whining and arguing won't lead you anywhere. Just respect the rules. You're the one seeking for help. Do your part of the job.

Comment: I copied and pasted all of your code to a proper IDE, and it doesn't throw the exception thrown in codeboard. Use a real development environment, and not that online IDE.

Comment: That occurred to me too but the project I need to submit requires it to be done online, after some research I had also found that the class path is the usual cause for this error but since it's an online IDE I don't have a class path. Thats what my question really was

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing

Comment: Ask your teacher how this online IDE is supposed to work. This is not a programming question.